# Simple JavaScript import/export on html not working

Tags: javascript, html, import, export

I just did a simple JavaScript on export/import and inserted it in the html I am having an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module". I did a search on StackOverflow and found that script type must be declared as "module".
After adding this, I get an error "class02.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///C:/xxx/yyyyy/animal.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https."

Below is my code :
animal.js:

```
export class Animal {
    constructor(type, legs) {
        this.type = type;
        this.legs = legs;
    }
}
```

class02.html :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module">
            import { Animal } from './animal.js';
            let cat = new Animal('Cat', 4);
            cat.legs = 3;
            alert(cat.legs);        
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Both class02.html and animal.js are in the same directory in my C drive.
Can somebody please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

To fix CORS error, you need to run html file on a server. You can install apache or nginx on your machine and run your code on it. In my case, I am using [Wamp](https://www.wampserver.com/en/) on Windows 10 and moved it to the www folder. It worked as well.